# Interpolate based on datetimes

Tags: python, interpolation, python-polars

In pandas, I can interpolate based on a datetimes like this:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ts": [
            datetime(2020, 1, 1),
            datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 0, 12),
            datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 1, 35),
            datetime(2020, 1, 4),
        ],
        "value": [1, np.nan, np.nan, 3],
    }
)
df1.set_index('ts').interpolate(method='index')
```

Outputs:

```py
                        value
ts
2020-01-01 00:00:00  1.000000
2020-01-03 00:00:12  2.333426
2020-01-03 00:01:35  2.334066
2020-01-04 00:00:00  3.000000
```

Is there a similar method in polars? Say, starting with

```py
df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "ts": [
            datetime(2020, 1, 1),
            datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 0, 12),
            datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 1, 35),
            datetime(2020, 1, 4),
        ],
        "value": [1, None, None, 3],
    }
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ ts                  ┆ value │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 2020-01-03 00:00:12 ┆ null  │
│ 2020-01-03 00:01:35 ┆ null  │
│ 2020-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3     │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

EDIT: I've updated the example to make it a bit more "irregular", so that `upsample` can't be used as a solution and to make it clear that we need something more generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses `scipy`. Conversion to `numpy` should be zero-copy for these values, so I think it should be efficient

```py
from scipy import interpolate
df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "ts": [
            datetime(2020, 1, 1),
            datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 0, 12),
            datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 1, 35),
            datetime(2020, 1, 4),
        ],
        "value": [1, None, None, 3],
    }
)
x = (
    df1.filter(pl.col("value").is_not_null())["ts"]
    .dt.timestamp()
    .to_numpy(zero_copy_only=True)
)
y = df1.filter(pl.col("value").is_not_null())[
    "value"
].to_numpy(zero_copy_only=True)
xnew = (
    df1["ts"].dt.timestamp().to_numpy(zero_copy_only=True)
)
ynew = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)(xnew)
df1 = df1.with_columns(pl.Series(ynew).alias("value"))
```

The result is

```py
In [6]: df1
Out[6]:
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ ts                  ┆ value    │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64      │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0      │
│ 2020-01-03 00:00:12 ┆ 2.333426 │
│ 2020-01-03 00:01:35 ┆ 2.334066 │
│ 2020-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3.0      │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems pandas upsampling first before doing interpolation. So, we can do the same thing in Polars by upsampling, then interpolating and then joining itself back so we only keep the datetimes you had initially:

```py
(df1
        .sort('ts')
        .with_columns(pl.col('value').cast(pl.Float64))
        .upsample(time_column='ts', every='1d')
        .interpolate()
        .join(
            df1.select('ts'), on='ts'
            )
        )
```

You also need to take care of the column dtype, it should be a float otherwise you get integer interpolation.

| ts(datetime[μs]) | value(f64) |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 1.0 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 2.333333 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | 3.0 |

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this only works `ts` has a regular frequency which I can upsample to, and won't work if `ts` is more irregular. I'll update the question to make this clear

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how useful this is but it looks like pandas calls `np.interp()` to do this:

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/missing.py#L481

```
invalid = pl.when(pl.col('value').is_null()).then(pl.col('ts')).alias('invalid')
valid   = pl.when(pl.col('value').is_not_null()).then(pl.col('ts')).alias('valid')
values  = pl.when(pl.col('value').is_not_null()).then(pl.col('value')).alias('values')

df.select(
   pl.struct(invalid, valid, values)
     .map(lambda args: 
         np.interp(
            args.struct['invalid'].drop_nulls().dt.timestamp().to_numpy(zero_copy_only=True), 
            args.struct['valid'].drop_nulls().dt.timestamp().to_numpy(zero_copy_only=True), 
            args.struct['values'].drop_nulls().to_numpy(zero_copy_only=True)
         )
     ) 
     .flatten()
)
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌──────────┐
│ invalid  │
│ ---      │
│ f64      │
╞══════════╡
│ 2.333426 │
│ 2.334066 │
└──────────┘
```

Although there does seem to be a lot of other stuff going on.